# Dúvida: Ajax acessar objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa noite, pessoal. poderiam me auxiliar em uma dúvida.

Montei um ajax para que possa atualizar a tabela de forma assíncrona, porem não consigo acessar o object do retorno do ajax.
meu codigo:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/api/vendedor",
}).done(function( data ) {
    var atualizaTable = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      console.log(value);
     atualizaTable += '<tr>';
     atualizaTable += '<td>'+ value.nome +'</td>';
     atualizaTable += '<td>'+ value.rg +'</td>';
     atualizaTable += '<td>'+ value.email +'</td>';
     atualizaTable += '<td>'+ value.totalVendas +'</td>';
     atualizaTable += '</tr>'
     });
     $('#atualizaTable').append(atualizaTable);
  });
});
```

Minha dúvida é em acessar os dados que está dentro da função  `$.each(data, function(key, value)` 
ele está me retornando dessa forma no console.log(value)

```
[{…}]
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "5ebdf58ef56ac5794a5bb047", nome: "Victor", rg: 19278080, email: "victor@gmail.com", totalVendas: 10, …}
1: {_id: "5ec3295b944349133c2100c7", nome: "JULIANO", rg: 10152020, email: "victorpadovan1997@gmail.com", totalVendas: 5, …}
2: {_id: "5ec32975944349133c2100c8", nome: "Juliano", rg: 1010, email: "victorpadovan1997@gmail.com", totalVendas: 2, …}
3: {_id: "5ec3297a944349133c2100c9", nome: "Juliano", rg: 1010, email: "victorpadovan1997@gmail.com", totalVendas: 2, …}
4: {_id: "5ec3299d944349133c2100ca", nome: "Juliano", rg: 1010, email: "victorpadovan1997@gmail.com", totalVendas: 2, …}
5: {_id: "5ec32a76944349133c2100cb", nome: "Juliano", rg: 1010, email: "victorpadovan1997@gmail.com", totalVendas: 2, …}
```

O que preciso fazer para acessar esses dados se passo um `value.nome` ele me retorna `undefined`
fico aguardando, obigado.

Comment: Tem um índice [0] aí. Tenta `value[0].nome`.

Comment: Simm, tem sim.
Porem eu tenho mais de um nome nesse indece se eu passar value[0].nome
ele acessa um cara só

Comment: E se eu acessar como citado ele me retorna:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome' of undefined

Comment: Como esta retornando os dados acessando somente o indice value[0]:    {_id: "5ebdf58ef56ac5794a5bb047", nome: "Victor", rg: 19278080, email: "victor@gmail.com", totalVendas: 10, …}

Comment: retorna undefined =(

Answer (score 0):

Para quem tiver a mesma dúvida eu passei um $.each para percorrer novamente

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "/api/vendedor",
          dataType: "json",
        }).done(function (data) {
          var atualizaTable = '';
          $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $.each(value, function (key, value) {
              atualizaTable += '<tr>';
              atualizaTable += '<td>' + value.nome + '</td>';
              atualizaTable += '<td>' + value.rg + '</td>';
              atualizaTable += '<td>' + value.email + '</td>';
              atualizaTable += '<td>' + value.totalVendas + '</td>';
              atualizaTable += '</tr>'
            });
            $('#atualizaTable').append(atualizaTable);
          });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que o data possui um índice [0] com arrays, logo você tem que fazer o .each no índice [0] do retorno, e não na raiz na array:

```
$.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
           ↑↑↑
```